# WooCommerce - Hide the category image on specific product category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm writing a spare parts website using the shoptimizer theme. Some category pages have complicated drawings that need to be displayed large as usual, which shoptimizer does as the category page displays the photo in large underneath the title. Other categories I could really do with the category pages displaying no category image at all, to bring the content up.

I can't seem to get my head around changing the archive-product.php template, so that it displays the category image for some pages and not for others. Is it possible someone can help me with this?

The part of the archive-product.php that pulls this image and the category description I think is the following:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
</header>
```

So I'd like a second template that I could to apply to certain templates, that doesn't Have this woocommerce_archive_description action, and some how apply that to specific categories, perhaps with the category ID code.

Comment: Hi Conor. Normally, the category description text and image is displayed on each category page. So it will display on page 1, page 2, page 3, etc etc. In the 
 [Shoptimizer docs](https://www.commercegurus.com/docs/shoptimizer-theme/category-description-first-page/) there is a good example on how you can remove the description from all other pages, except page 1. You can adjust that code snippet with your preferred page or it can also be tweaked for specific category IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to alter template for that. Look into `content-product-cat.php` template and you will notice action `woocommerce_before_subcategory_title` which will call for `woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail` function . If we [look into that function](https://wp-kama.com/filecode/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2684-2712), you will notice if you dont provide image will load the default one `wc_placeholder_img_src()` .

So you need to use `remove_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title','woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail');` to remove the original function and provide your own function.

I'm going to simply copy/paste the original function and remove the else part. You can alter the function as you want.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'theme_subcategory_thumbnail', 10, 1);

function theme_subcategory_thumbnail($category) {
    $small_thumbnail_size = apply_filters( 'subcategory_archive_thumbnail_size', 'woocommerce_thumbnail' );
    $dimensions           = wc_get_image_size( $small_thumbnail_size );
    $thumbnail_id         = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );

    if ( $thumbnail_id ) {
        $image        = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, $small_thumbnail_size );
        $image        = $image[0];
        $image_srcset = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_srcset' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $thumbnail_id, $small_thumbnail_size ) : false;
        $image_sizes  = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_sizes' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $thumbnail_id, $small_thumbnail_size ) : false;
    } 
    //else part is removed

    if ( $image ) {
        $image = str_replace( ' ', '%20', $image );

        // Add responsive image markup if available.
        if ( $image_srcset && $image_sizes ) {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $category->name ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $dimensions['width'] ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $dimensions['height'] ) . '" srcset="' . esc_attr( $image_srcset ) . '" sizes="' . esc_attr( $image_sizes ) . '" />';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $category->name ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $dimensions['width'] ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $dimensions['height'] ) . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution may have got this the wrong way round; We need the thumbnail to display on the parent category page for the category tile. However when you click through to the category itself I want the large image at the top of the page to be hidden. 

Is this solution the correct way to achieve this? it might be the 'thumbnail' part that is throwing me off

Comment: This is more like theme issue not wtih woo its self. Woo doesnt have big image on top by default. Provide more details in your question like what function is used to show that element or if its popular theme what theme you are using. If its premium your best bet is to contact the author for instructions.

Comment: Thanks snuffy, I understand why I haven't been able to find much on this as it isn't standard WooCommerce behaviour. I've updated the post now, hopefully its clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Richard in the comments, I've now discovered the answer to this, by modifying a code snippet in the Shoptimizer docs:

```
add_action( 'wp', function() {
    // Define the category IDs where you want to remove the description and image
    $category_ids = array( 50, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71 );

    // Check if the current page is a category page and matches the specified category IDs
    if ( is_product_category( $category_ids ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'shoptimizer_woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'shoptimizer_category_image', 20 );
    }
}, 20 );
```

I can confirm this is working on my website, successfully removing the category banner image from the categories which ID's are in the array.